# Docker for Python get DOCKER_HOST

Tags: python, docker, python-docker

I'm trying to find the DOCKER_HOST for my docker registry.

Looking at the sdk, I know it's possible to set the DOCKER_HOST.

[image]

But is it possible to find the current DOCKER_HOST been used?

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
client.info()
```

Comment: I suppose the current one would be in `os.environ['DOCKER_HOST']`.

Comment: I did try this: docker_host = os.environ['DOCKER_HOST'] 

and I got KeyError: DOCKER_HOST

Answer (score 1):

`DOCKER_HOST` is an optional value.

The default Docker host (and local registry) is a socket on localhost. I wouldn't expect that you'll find a `DOCKER_HOST` set unless you have chosen to set one.

Various things can override, however, so it really depends on your local environment and setup.

- `DOCKER_HOST` value
- `DOCKER_CONTEXT` value
- A context set using the `docker context` command
- A context set using the `-c` flag to the `docker` command

[Reference (docs.docker.com)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/)